# Cast as date - literal does not match format string

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting

i have this select :

```
 select P.DT03_DT as PROPOSAL_DATE,
        p.dt02_dt as DATE_OF_JUDGEMENT,
        P.DT05_DT as END_DATE,
        cast('20140704' as date) as Dt  

       from imxdb.t_intervenants i    
         join imxdb.g_indivparam p
       on i.refindividu = p.refindividu

        where p.type = 'BANCRUPTCY'    
         AND (to_char(p.dt02_dt, 'yyyymmdd') ='20140704' or
         to_char(P.DT05_DT, 'yyyymmdd') = '20140704')
```

and this gives me error :

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
>                             01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"

but when i just commment the line "cast('20140704' as date) as Dt " its working fine, why?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

Let me explain with a small example :

My `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `DD-MON-RR`

```
SQL> SELECT VALUE FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER='NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------
DD-MON-RR

SQL>
```

I can verify that in SQL*Plus :

```
SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
---------
23-SEP-14

SQL>
```

Now, if I use to `CAST` a date literal in unknown format, I will get an error :

```
SQL> SELECT CAST('20140704' AS DATE) AS DT FROM DUAL;
SELECT CAST('20140704' AS DATE) AS DT FROM DUAL
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string


SQL>
```

So, I will give the required `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, and it should be fine :

```
SQL> SELECT CAST('23-sep-14' AS DATE) AS DT  FROM DUAL;

DT
---------
23-SEP-14

SQL>
```

Other alternatives,

- Change the NLS_DATE_FORMAT
- Alter it at session level.
- Alternatively, you can use `TO_DATE` and use proper `FORMAT

It will `OVERRIDE` the `locale-specific NLS settings`.

```
SQL> select to_date('20140704', 'YYYYMMDD') from dual;

TO_DATE('
---------
04-JUL-14
```

If you want to display in your `desired format`, then use `TO_CHAR`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the line

```
cast('20140704' as date) as Dt
```

with

```
TO_DATE('20140704','YYYYMMDD') as Dt
```

Comment: It depends on the NLS settings. `TO_DATE` will work because it overrides the locale-NLS settings.